# Can criterion be used for profiling concurrency across multiple cores?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc, haskell-criterion

I notice that when I run a criterion benchmark (which does no `forkIO` or `par`) compiled with `-O2  -rtsopts -threaded -eventlog` and `+RTS -N2 -ls` that real work (not just GC) is spread across both cores. A quick grep of the criterion source didn't show where the parallelism was originating.

I'd like to do some careful benchmarks measuring e.g. contentious updates on an MVar between two threads; can I do that accurately with criterion (for instance if all of that parallelism is happening between tests)?

Comment: Can you write a notice into the eventlog at the start of the benchmark?

Comment: @JohnL good suggestion; I tried and it looks like criterion isn't trying to do any parallelism during test code execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stuck a `traceEventIO` before and after each IO action under test, and it looks entirely single-threaded for the duration of the test code execution, so I think I should be good.